# Better way to access a nested foreign key field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, foreign-keys

Consider the following models

```
class A(models.Model):
  id
  field1
  field2

class B(models.Model):
  id
  field3
  field_a (foreign_key to Class A)

class C(models.model):
  id
  field4
  field5
  field_b (foreign_key to Class B)

  @property
  def nested_field(self):
    return self.field_b.field_a
```

Now here that property in class C, would trigger additional SQL queries to be fetched. Is there an optimized or better way to get nested foreign key fields?

I have basically tried searching and finding regarding this and couldn't find a better solution, that addresses this problem.

Comment: One tool that you're looking for is [`select_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related). You just have to make sure that the queryset that fetches the objects has selected or otherwise joined the fields referenced on your model property. `annotate()` is also useful if you don't want to risk expensive queries being called from model instances.

Comment: @Supra621 so in the end , it doesn't matter while defining a property in class , how the queryset is evaluated would determine the number of SQL queries that execute.

Comment: In this case, yes. If you want to change the default SQL query of a model class to always fetch the related fields you want in your model properties, you can [use a custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) that overrides the default queryset to include a call to `select_related()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer: `select_related()` is one of the go-to tools. As you noticed, the model instance needs to have been fetched by a queryset that has made the appropriate call to `select_related()`.

```py
queryset = C.objects.select_related('b__a')
obj = queryset.first()
print(obj.nested_field)  # Shouldn't cost additional queries
```

The main reason I turned this into an answer is to mention a tradeoff: `select_related()` does the equivalent of `SELECT *` on the *related model(s)*.  It's convenient when you want to have the related model instance available, and not much of a problem for most small models; however, if you have a related model with a lot of columns, or several distantly nested models, this can cause unnecessary overhead if you don't need to use all the fields that are being retrieved.

You can optimize this using `only()`, but what I've used more often is `annotate()`. I feel like `annotate()` gets overlooked for these kinds of common foreign key traversals, but it can give you a similar interface to using model properties (and it took me **way** too long into my coding career to figure that out):

```py
from django.db.models import F

queryset = C.objects.annotate(nested_field_1=F('field_b__field_a__field1'))
obj = queryset.first()
print(obj.nested_field_1)  # similar, though it's per-field
```

`annotate()` does the equivalent of `SELECT AS` here, and it can accomplish many of the same things as a Model property. Here, `nested_field_1` is available as an attribute on each object in the query result.

To make this more reusable, these kinds of calls to `annotate()` can be added to a custom `Manager`:

```py
from django.db.models import Manager, Model

class ModelCManager(Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return (
            super().get_queryset()
            .annotate(nested_field_1=F('field_b__field_a__field1'))
        )

class C(Model):
    ...
    objects = Manager()
    with_nested = ModelCManager()


queryset = C.with_nested.all()
obj = queryset.first()
print(obj.nested_field_1)
```

In a production application where I had a LOT of normalized, nested foreign keys, I would more frequently extend `QuerySet` so that I could chain additional methods together:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Model, QuerySet

class ModelCQuerySet(Queryset):
    def annotate_a_fields(self):
        return self.annotate(
            a_field_1=F('field_b__field_a__field1'),
            a_field_2=F('field_b__field_a__field2')
        )
    
    def annotate_b_fields(self):
        return self.annotate(
            b_field_1=F('field_b__field1')
        )

class C(Model):
    ...
    objects = ModelCQuerySet.as_manager()


queryset = (
    C.objects
    .filter(field_b__field4=42)
    .annotate_a_fields()
    .annotate_b_fields()
)
obj = queryset.first()
print(obj.a_field_1)
```

With the above, you have a lot of control over the interface you create, and it makes the queries involved to get the data you want obvious. Model properties are still super useful for *local* column operations, like joining strings or formatting values - but I've been burned enough times by surprise 9000+ implicit queries that I avoid defining any model properties that have to traverse a foreign key. Moving those data retrieval concerns to the `QuerySet` helped guard against some of those accidents.